# Get a single document from Firebase Firestore query with Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, stream

I know this might seem obvious, but I just can't find a way to do it..

I am trying to get **a single document** from a firebase query. When I say a single document I mean **not a stream**.

My approach so far is:

```
MyClass getDocument(String myQueryString) {
    return Firestore.instance.collection('myCollection').where("someField", isEqualTo: myQueryString) //This will almost certainly return only one document
        .snapshots().listen(
            (querySnapshot) => _myClassFromSnapshot(querySnapshot.documents[0])
    );
  }
```

However, I am getting the error `A value of type 'StreamSubscription<QuerySnapshot>' can't be returned from method 'getDocument' because it has a return type of 'MyClass'.`

Thanks!

Comment: Hello, have you tried: databaseReference.collection('myCollection').getDocuments().then();

Comment: Sounds good, but it's missing the query part..

Would it be something like :
databaseReference.collection('myCollection').where("field", isEqualTo: myString).then()

?

How do I get only the first document?

Comment: databaseReference.collection("myCollection").getDocuments().then((onValue) {
      onValue.documents.forEach((f) { f[0] })});

Comment: @AndresSilva Try limiting the query to 1 result if all u need is the first doc in the query result use ‘.limit()’

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for your replies,

I finally got it to work by doing this:

```
Future<MyClass> getDocument(String myQueryString) {
    return Firestore.instance.collection('myCollection')
        .where("someField", isEqualTo: myQueryString)
        .limit(1)
        .getDocuments()
        .then((value) {
            if(value.documents.length > 0){
              return _myClassFromSnapshot(value.documents[0]);
            } else {
              return null;
            }
          },
        );
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

**Update 2021:**

```dart
var collection = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('myCollection');
var querySnapshot = await collection 
    .where('someField', isEqualTo: queryString)
    .get();

for (var snapshot in querySnapshot.docs) {
  Map<String, dynamic> data = snapshot.data();
}
```

You can retrieve the data from the map object using

```dart
var fooValue = data['foo'];
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update Okt 2021**

```
var coll = Firestore.instance.collection('yourcollection');
var qs = await coll.doc('yourdocument').get();
Map<String,dynamic> value = qs.data();
Map<String,dynamic> getField = jsonDecode(value['specific value in field']);
var valueInfield = getField['data'];
print($valueInfield);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).